# rsync-path in expect script

Tags: tcl, expect, rsync

I have written a backup script that uses `expect` to automate `rsync`.

To make sure all files get backed up, I use `rsync`'s [`--rsync-path="sudo rsync"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92125/20230) option.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

expect <<- DONE
    spawn rsync --rsync-path="sudo\\ rsync" -uav myuser@example.com:/home/myuser/ /backups/home/myuser
    expect ":"
    send -- "mypassword\r"
    expect eof
DONE
```

This does not work as intended. I get the following error message:

```
bash: sudo rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

I have seen [similar questions](https://serverfault.com/q/234876/127106) with respect to using spaces in a `rsync` command line, and have added single quotes, double quotes, and escape backslashes here and there, but nothing has worked yet.

How do I make "`--rsync-path` with spaces" work within an `expect` script?

Comment: Any reason why you don't `spawn sudo rsync ...`?

Comment: @Jens, yes, two reasons for not using `spawn sudo rsync ...`: 1. `rsync` is supposed to run with sudo rights on the *remote* system. ... 2. My local machine does not have `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got this:

```
--rsync-path="sudo\\ rsync"
```

Inside Expect/Tcl, this is seen as:

```
--rsync-path="sudo rsync"
```

And, because Tcl's quoting rules are *not* the same as bash's, that then uses `"sudo rsync"` *with the double quotes* as the command to send to the remote side. Which confuses things terribly. The correct fix is to omit the double quotes; the (backslash-quoted) backslash will ensure that it all gets into spawn as one argument, and gets sent to the other side correctly.

---

I really don't like using HEREdocs with Tcl. Too many things can go weird when different sorts of quoting interact. It's much better to use a single script in the real target language, since then you can use variables to make things clearer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set remoteRsync "sudo rsync"
set from myuser@example.com:/home/myuser/
set to   /backups/home/myuser
set pass "mypassword"

spawn rsync --rsync-path=$remoteRsync -uav $from $to
expect ":"
send -- "$pass\r"
expect eof
exit
```

This makes the structure of the code much simpler to see, and easier to debug. The bit with `/usr/bin/env` at the start is just a way to avoid having the bash wrapper.

And no, those variables won't need quoting at use. Tcl is not bash.

Comment: Awesome, using Tcl's `set` to assign values to variables solved my problem. And by escaping all Tcl variable references (e.g., `$from` becomes `\$from`) I can still use the here-document approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `--rsync-path` to do that, since what you want is *word-splitting*, i.e. something the *shell* does.

So how can you run a command that runs a command by specifying a single pathname?

On the remote system, write a script wrapper `susync` doing the `sudo` (don't forget to `chmod 755`):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/sudo /path/to/rsync "$@"
```

and use

```
spawn rsync --rsync-path=/path/to/susync ...
```

Comment: *You can't use --rsync-path to do that, since what you want is word-splitting, i.e. something the shell does.*. Then how come I can run `rsync --rsync-path="sudo\\ rsync" -uav myuser@example.com:/home/myuser/ /backups/home/myuser` directly on my local bash shell successfully? The remote also uses bash shell.

Comment: @Abdull Maybe because as a client, rsync uses `system("x")`, but in the server it uses `exec("x")`. The first calls a shell, the second executes x directly. It's all speculation.

Comment: In my (very special) case this workaround was easier than debugging the crazy string manipulations that my shell was doing. Thanks Jens